# Is there a reason a thread shouldn't access other thread's stack?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I was just playing with Intel Parallel inspector on my project, and it displays a warning:

> One or more threads in the application accessed the stack of another
>   thread. This may indicate one or more bugs in your application.

I do indeed have some objects that are allocated on stack shared between threads. I don't see why this is a problem. Any hints?

Comment: AFAIK it's hugely inefficient.

Comment: How do you know the stack frame is still good in another thread?

Comment: Well, is there a reason you should not just walk into another person's house?

Comment: @H2CO3: as long as I know where that person keeps the stuff I need? I don't see any :)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Programs are not people.  Threads are not houses.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Think of the _person_ as it has a housekeeper, that will store the stuff at random places, you don't know about ...

Comment: @g-makulik: I think this house analogy is going out of hand...

Comment: @VioletGiraffe May be! But seriously: How do you know if an object allocated on another threads stack has gone out of scope or not, if the address/reference was passed to another thread? Consider using `std::shared_ptr` or similar, instead passing raw stack addresses or references in between threads.

Comment: @g-makulik: I know for sure the object exists, I've designed it that way. I am not sure now, though, that passing references to stack to other threads is legitimate, i. e., if stack object addresses are stable. I thought they are. Am I wrong there?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Depends all on the synchronization mechanisms you use to control access to the instances in question. But in such situation you describe, I'd guess you don't need handling in different threads, synchronous access should do well. Don't confuse existence of instances on the stack with heap allocated instances! May be you should add a short code sample to elaborate your situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Imagine this -- a thread is executing and a method is called which has a local (stack) variable (an object). It adds this object to a work queue, a queue which is processed by a separate thread.

That thread gets to the item added by the first thread and accesses the object, on the stack, of the first thread.

What has the first thread done in the meantime?  It may have exited the method and freed up that stack space. That freed space may or may not be re-used.  The second thread accessing the stack of the first thread may or may not work correctly, depending on timing and the call graph.

If you know the stack variable will exist while the second thread processes it then it can be safe to do; for example, if Thread 1 queues a stack variable and then blocks until Thread 2 notifies it has finished processing, that is a safe operation.

A warning rather than an error is issued because this may or may not be a legitimate operation, and there's no way for an analyzer to be certain.

Comment: Looks like I don't know enough about how the stack works. But once the object is placed on stack, isn't its address fixed and stable? Is passing this address to another thread an error as long as I know the object still exists in th thread that owns it?

Comment: It is not correct to say "it may have exited."  The program could be designed so that the function *does not* exit while the object in its stack frame is being used by another thread.

Comment: Yes @DietrichEpp - the program *could* be designed that way. I say it *may* have exited; of course that implies that it may *not* have exited, but the analyzer can't know that so it issues the warning.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe _'But once the object is placed on stack, isn't its address fixed and stable?'_ No! The object is destroyed as soon the current scope (e.g. function or `{}`-block) is left

Comment: @g-makulik: That much is obvious. That's not what I asked. As long as long as the object exists (of course I made sure it exists as long as I need it to), is passing its reference to other threads valid?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe - `is passing its reference to other threads valid?` Yes, as long as you make sure it still exists (the current stack frame is not exited) it is valid to pass that reference to another thread. The Intel Parallel Inspector is going to warn about it because it's error-prone and often done by mistake.

Answer (score 10):

It's not *wrong,* it's just possibly wrong.  Tools like Intel Parallel Inspector that provide additional diagnostics for your program must make a tradeoff between false positives and false negatives, in this case, it seems that the developers thought that accessing the stack of another thread was much more likely to be an error (low false positive rate if reported) than not (high false negative rate if not reported).

Valgrind is another example of a tool that can signal errors in code that is correct.

The real question here is, "what is the other thread doing?"  If you think, "maybe it will return from that function and the stack frame will be invalid," then you are doing parallel programming wrong.  No answer about multithreaded behavior should be qualified with "maybe".  You had better make sure that that thread doesn't return, for example, by making it wait on a semaphore or condition variable, or by making it join with the other threads.

### Discussion

**Pubby:** "AFAIK it's hugely inefficient."

The only reason it would be inefficient is because you might have multiple cores modifying the same cache lines, which is the same problem you have with other kinds of shared memory.

**Collin:** How do you know the stack frame is still good in another thread?

If you use something in multiple threads, you use some kind of synchronization mechanism to ensure that it's not modified in an invalid way.  This situation is no different.

**H2CO3:** Well, is there a reason you should not walk into another person's house?

If we're going to play with analogies, I'd say that the process is the house, and each of the threads are people in the house.  If Dave keeps a list of chores in his room, I'll go into his room every time I need to look at the list.  If he stops doing that, he'd better tell me or else I'll start writing on random pieces of paper on his desk.

### Conclusion

It's a matter of style whether this program behavior is acceptable or not.